# Clone of a div with its all content like button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code, in this code when I do .clone() of div photo then it only do clone of div 'photo' without button. I want to clone whole div with content (button and div here).How can I do it? Thank you

HTML:

```
      <div class="photo">
        <button>Delete</button>
      </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
         var $photo = $('.photo').clone();
         $('.photo').html($photo);
```

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) function has an extra parameter called `withDataAndEvents`

> withDataAndEvents (default: false) Type: Boolean A Boolean indicating
>
> whether event handlers and data should be copied along with the
>   elements. The default value is false

So in your case the following code should fix your problem.

```
var $photo = $('.photo').clone(true);
```

Small example:

http://jsfiddle.net/5tT3P/1/

Comment: Thanks bro but its not working. Only photo div is cloned not the delete button.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as expected in Chrome, Safari and Firefox (latest, OSX). Are you trying to clone the contents only?

With this HTML:

```
<div class="photo">
   <button>Delete</button>
</div>
```

and this JS:

```
var $photo = $('.photo').clone();
$('.photo').html($photo);
```

The new HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="photo">
    <div class="photo"> <-- because a clone of .photo is being inserted into .photo -->
        <button>Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you append it to a new div, there is no `.photo>.photo` and the button is visible.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8K2ty/2/)**
Fiddle.